# iOS not calling function but can see function exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm struggling to debug an issue as I cannot think of any reasoning why this is happening. Is there any reason why the following would not work properly in iOS but fine in every other browser?

```
alert($('#id')[0].3rdPartyLibrary.someFunction); 
//successfully alerts the code within someFunction

$('#id')[0].3rdPartyLibrary.someFunction(); 
//is called in all browsers but not in iOS also stops execution of anything below

alert('not hit in iOS');
//but is fine in all other browsers
```

Comment: May be u should post the code of someFunction

Comment: So you're storing a function in a host object?

Comment: @zerkms which one do you think is a host object?

Comment: Most likely, `someFunction` throws an exception. Less likely, `someFunction` is actually a string.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak: oops, in DOM NODE object. But, hm, aren't they host objects?

Comment: @zerkms oops, didn't notice the `[0]`. Yeah, that's a bad idea.

Comment: @JanDvorak You were right! `someFunction` was throwing an exception - managed to track it down and get round it. Odd how there was different behavior for iOS. Thanks for your help everyone.